# HiGHS Solver PuLP Imprimentation

Tags: solver, pulp, highs

Having some issues defining the gapRel/mip_abs_gap option with the PuLP integration. The PuLP documentation states that HiGHS_CMD implementation should have the gapRel parameter, but the HiGHS_CMD function does not accept it. HiGHS documentation states that it can be configured via options and mip_abs_gap parameter. However, I'm not able to add this option in my code. Alread tried:

```
milp.setSolver(HiGHS_CMD(msg=True, timeLimit=100, options=['mip_abs_gap=0.001'], path=highs_path))
milp.setSolver(HiGHS_CMD(msg=True, timeLimit=100, options='mip_abs_gap=0.001', path=highs_path))
milp.setSolver(HiGHS_CMD(msg=True, timeLimit=100, mip_abs_gap=0.001, path=highs_path))
milp.setSolver(HiGHS_CMD(msg=True, timeLimit=100, gapRel=0.001, path=highs_path))
```

But everything returns an error. How am I supposed to enter the options?